# POSIXct not accepting custom origin

Tags: r, posixct

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I'm importing some data which is stored as HH:MM:SS. I'm trying to convert this to POSIXct and manually specify the origin as the date the data was collected.

```
datIn$TimeComplete <- as.POSIXct(datIn$Time, format="%H:%M:%S", origin="2000-01-01", tz="CET")
```

The output of this registers the HH:MM:SS correctly but says the day is 2019-03-05 (today) and I can't seem to convince it to do anything different.

Comment: can you add your data and the expected answer so we can help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the concept of `origin`. Origin is there to help convert numbers to dates. Those numbers represent seconds so you need the `origin` in order to add those seconds to the origin and get the datetime object. For example,

```
as.POSIXct(60, tz = "GMT", origin = '2015-03-05')
#[1] "2015-03-05 00:01:00 GMT"
as.POSIXct(3600, tz = "GMT", origin = '2015-07-05')
#[1] "2015-07-05 01:00:00 GMT"
```

What you are trying to do can be easily achieved by pasting the desired date to your times and converting to datetime, i.e.

```
as.POSIXct(paste0('2000-01-01 ', '11:03:15'), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", origin = "", tz = "CET")
#[1] "2000-01-01 11:03:15 CET"
```